# CMOS 4000 series postfix meaning: BCL, BCP, BD

Tags: integrated-circuit, simulation, cmos

I am simulating a digital circuit and I need to use a CMOS inverter 4009. There are three of them with different postfixes:

1. 4009BCL
2. 4009BCP
3. 4009BD

What are the differences between BCL and BCP and BD?

Comment: Are they DIFFERENT **SIMULATIONS**?  Or do they all use the same simulation.  Seems likely they are just package variants.

Comment: Three types has been offered in the same simulator (Multisim) for each CMOS 4000 series IC. yes I think you are right, it just about their package cases. The model specifications in the simulator are all the same for all the three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCL and BCP and BD are just referring to casing. So all three are the same.